# Regex: Capturing all digits in a string, and returning as a new string of digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture all the digits of an input string. The string can also contain other characters like letters so I can't simply do `[0-9]+`.

I've tried `/[0-9]/g` but this returns all digits as an array.

How do you capture, or match, every instance of a digit and return as a string?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: JavaScript. I updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Just replace all the non-digits from the original string:

```
var s = "foo 123 bar 456";
var digits = s.replace(/\D+/g, "");
```

Comment: You could use \D instead of [^\d]

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the non-digits character rather than extracting the `digits`:

```
var str = "some string 22 with digits 2131";
str = str.replace(new RegExp("\D","g"),"");
```

`\D` is same as `[^\d]`.

Comment: My JavaScript is pretty weak, but won't that need to be `"[^\\d]"`?

Comment: @DSM.. No, you don't need to double escape it in Javascript. That is only required in Java. The only thing that I don't like about Java, when it comes to Regex.

Comment: Hmm.  Running each in `rhino`, `\d` gives me `d` and `\\d` gives me `222131`.

Comment: @DSM. Strange. [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=[^\d]%2B&input=%22some%20string%2022%20with%20digits%202131%22) gives me the opposite.

Comment: @Mathletics: ah, that's probably it.  Likely they didn't bother adjusting some dialect-like quirks like that.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are better, but to do it just as you asked, you simply need to join the array.

```
var str = "this 1 string has 2 digits";
var result = str.match(/[0-9]+/g).join(''); // 12
```